# SQL select statement with 2 conditions

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table that has columns `CustomerCell` and `ReceiptType`. I need to create a `SELECT` statement that displays every record that matches `CustomerCell` or `ReceiptType`.

I tried this code:

```
If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length <> 0 OrElse CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Dim ds As New DataTable
    Dim sqlstr As String = "Select [RcptNum], [RcptDate], [RcptCustName], [RcptCustCell], [RcptAmount], [RcptType], [RcptFld1], [RcptFld2], [RcptFld3], [RcptUser] From [tblReceipt] where (RcptCustCell = '" & TextBox1.Text & "') or ([RcptType] = 'Cash') "
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, Conn)
    ds.Reset()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, Conn)
    da.Fill(ds)
    dgv.DataSource = ds
    Call griddraw()
    Conn.Close()
End If
```

Where `Textbox1` is for `CustomerCell` and `CheckBox4` is for `ReceiptType`. When I enter customer cell and receipt type I should see 2 records however with the above code I can see only one record.

This is my form:

[image]

Comment: Abstract your issue from .NET code. When you run the SQL, what are you getting in SSMS?

Comment: FYI, you have a giant security hole in your system. Please read up on SQL Injection and Parameterized SQL

Comment: @Ghost, I've tried that in SSMS with correct result, but wrong in vb.net

Comment: Either you are connecting to the wrong database or the SQL being generated isn't EXACTLY what is being ran in SSMS. Put a break point in and get the exact SQL string you are generating and try that in SSMS

Comment: @Ghost, remember that in vb.net i have a textbox and checkbox, textbox must not be null and checkbox must be checked.

Comment: check in execution time which is the value of sqlstr and then run it in SSMS.

Comment: Guys, i upload a photo of my form, so... how can i make a search  with one or more criteria as shown above?

Answer (score 2):

As stated, look into parameters to avoid SQL injection and it does clear up your query a little more. I've put this together which may help. Might need a few tweaks for your application:

```
If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length <> 0 OrElse CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
   Dim dt As DataTable
   Dim sqlstr As String = "Select [RcptNum], [RcptDate], [RcptCustName], [RcptCustCell], [RcptAmount], [RcptType], [RcptFld1], [RcptFld2], [RcptFld3], [RcptUser] From [tblReceipt] where (RcptCustCell = @RcptCustCell) or ([RcptType] = 'Cash') "
   Using con As New SqlConnection(constr),
         com As New SqlCommand(sqlstr, con)

       com.Parameters.Add("@RcptCustCell", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text

       con.Open()

       dt = New DataTable
       dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)

       dgv.DataSource = dt
       Call griddraw()
  End Using
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(constr)
Dim ds As New DataTable
Dim sqlstr As String = "Select [RcptNum], [RcptDate], [RcptCustName], [RcptCustCell], [RcptAmount], [RcptType], [RcptFld1], [RcptFld2], [RcptFld3], [RcptUser] From [tblReceipt]"

If TextBox1.Text.trim.length <> 0 then
  sqlstr += "where (RcptCustCell = '" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
endif
If chkPaymentCheck.checked then
  if sqlstr.contains("where") = false then
    sqlstr += "where RcptType = 'Check'"
  EndIf
  sqlstr += "or RcptType = 'Check'"
endif
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, Conn)
ds.Reset()
da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, Conn)
da.Fill(ds)
dgv.DataSource = ds
Call griddraw()
Conn.Close()
```

Try this and you can continue with the if statements to add more checks.

Comment: Hi, if you need more explanation about the current question, please make it in comments no here in the answers, because you can't answer something that you do not understand.

Comment: be nice, but i can't comment on the question, you need atleast 50 rep points, you can only comment on your own anser.

Comment: sorry if i sound rude, in this case try to win points making other things and then you can make comments :).